# Creating a modified capitalize method in Ruby from scratch

Tags: ruby, methods, capitalization, capitalize

I am learning methods in Ruby and thought that the best way to learn them was to create a method that already exists. However, there are two problems that I am running in to:

1. I do not know what the capitalize method looks like
2. My solution (it does more than the original method does) seems like it can be refactored into something more elegant.

This is what I have come up with:

```
# method that capitalizes a word
def new_capitalize(string)
  if string[0].downcase == "m" && string[1].downcase == "c"
    puts "#{string[0].upcase}#{string[1].downcase}#{string[2].upcase}#{string[3..-1].downcase}"
  else
    puts "#{string[0].upcase}#{string[1..-1].downcase}"
  end
end

name1 = "ryan"
name2 = "jane"

new_capitalize(name1) # prints "Ryan"
new_capitalize(name2) # prints "Jane"

str = "mCnealy"
puts str.capitalize 
       # prints "Mcnealy"

new_capitalize(str) 
       # prints "McNealy"
```

It seems as if the first part of my if statement could be made much more efficient. It does not need to be even close to my solution as long as it prints the second capital if the name begins with "mc"

Also, if someone could point me to where the built in capitalize method's code could be found that would be great too!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is poorly-worded. Your first sentence contradicts the title and what you are attempting to do with your code. It's important that your statement of the question be complete and unambiguous. One or more examples would be helpful. When you give examples, show your expected or desired result and assign a variable to each input object (e.g,, `str = "mCnealy"`) so readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. Post your code after you have clearly stated your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, how about:

```
module NameRules
  refine String do
    def capitalize
      if self[0..1].downcase == 'mc'
        "Mc#{self[2..-1].capitalize}"
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then to use it:

```
class ThingWithNames
  using NameRules

  def self.test(string)
   string.capitalize
  end
end

ThingWithNames.test('mclemon') # => "McLemon"
ThingWithNames.test('lemon') # => "Lemon"
```

If we were starting from scratch and not using the `C` implemented code:

```
module NameRules
  refine String do
    def capitalize
      if self[0..1].downcase == 'mc'
        "Mc#{self[2..-1].capitalize}"
      else
        new_string = self.downcase
        new_string[0] = new_string[0].upcase
        new_string
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Reference materials:

[`String#capitalize` source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L6095-L6153)
[A really good presentation on refinements](http://interblah.net/why-is-nobody-using-refinements)

Comment: Awesome reference material! Thank you, and nice to see something that I've never heard of before.

Answer (score 1):

First, in my opinion, doing anything other than capitalizing the first letter of the string should be a different method or an optional arg you pass. Second, if you are trying to mimic the core lib behavior than you could monkey-patch String.

```
class String
  def capitalize
    self[0].upcase << self[1..-1].downcase
  end
end
```

The closest to an official ruby implementation is probably Rubinius

https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/377d5c958bc8239514fb98701b75859c6b51b9d4/core/string.rb#L332

Comment: May I recommend using `downcase` on what you're appending i.e. `self[1..-1].downcase` to further mimick the 'real' `String#capitalize`.

Comment: I agree, especially after watching the link about refinements in @Azolo's post, thanks for the insight!